# Monotouch UISwipeGestureRecognizer on and UIImageView

Tags: xamarin.ios

on my View i have an Image View. I added a UISwipeGestureRecognicer to this image View with                        this.Pad_imgHeader.AddGestureRecognizer(sgrRight);

On a normal View it works. But why it doesn´t work on an UIImageView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, user interaction is disable for UIImageViews (and UILabels also). Therefore, the UIImageView does not respond to touches.
Try setting it to true and then add the gesture:

```
this.Pad_imgHeader.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
this.Pad_imgHeader.AddGestureRecognizer(sgrRight);
```